# Delete everything in a directory except a file in C#

Tags: c#, file, delete-file

I am having trouble deleting everything in a directory except a file (index.dat)
I am trying to clear the cookies folder and the temp folder of files but I get an error when I try to delete index.dat because its being used by another process. Is there a way to delete everything in the temp and cookies folder *except* the index.dat file? Here is my code:

```
string userProfile = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE");
string strDirLocalq = Path.Combine(userProfile, "AppData");
string strDirLocalw = Path.Combine(strDirLocalq, "Roaming");
string strDirLocale = Path.Combine(strDirLocalw, "Microsoft");
string strDirLocalr = Path.Combine(strDirLocale, "Windows");
string strDirLocalt = Path.Combine(strDirLocalr, "Cookies");

string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(strDirLocalt);
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
    File.Delete(filePath);
```

Comment: You can put your `File.Delete()` inside a try/catch block to handle files you can't delete, without disrupting the loop (if you so chose).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works:

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(strDirLocalt);
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
{
    var name = new FileInfo(filePath).Name;
    name = name.ToLower();
    if (name != "index.dat")
    {
        File.Delete(filePath);
    }
}
```

Comment: You're welcome :-) I modified it slightly to use FileInfo class.

Comment: instead of `Directory.GetFiles(strDirLocalt)` use `new DirectoryInfo(strDirLocalt).GetFiles()` which returns `List<FileInfo>` then you can just do `fi.Delete();`

Answer (score 4):

Check out this interesting solution!

```
List<string> files = new List<string>(System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(strDirLocalt));
files.ForEach(x => { try { System.IO.File.Delete(x); } catch { } });
```

Feel the beauty of the language!

Comment: This worked too. Thanks! It grabs any file that is currently "in use" too and blocks it from being deleted.

Comment: Lambdas make this lang pleasure to use:)

Answer (score 2):

Simply place a try/catch around the File.Delete because there could be more files that are in use which will also throw exceptions.

```
try
{
  File.Delete(filePath);
}
catch (Exception ignore)
{
}
```

Comment: This is good. Anyway, you still need to loop through files, so I would combine the 2 solution: tster's and Hams's

Answer (score 1):

```
string[] filePaths = Directory.GetFiles(strDirLocalt); 
foreach (string filePath in filePaths)
 try {
   File.Delete(filePath);
 }
 catch{ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter it from the list

```
foreach (string filePath in filePaths.Where(!filePath.Contains("index.dat"))
    File.Delete(filePath);
```

Comment: If you were to apply this more generically, it would be a pain to modify the list of files which are to be skipped. If you were to use the where-not style, it may save you time in the future to put all skipped files into a static array, then use `filePaths.Where(fp=>!skipped.Any(s=>fp.Contains(s)))`...

Answer (score 0):

Why not just catch the exception - there is the possiblility that any of the files could be in use when you attempt to delete them.

```
try{
     // delete
}
catch{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One method that might still work is to boot-up in safe mode and then assign yourself administrator rights and then see if you can find the files to delete them

The method I now use is to create a batch file to rename the subfolder below the folder containing the index.bat files and to then only copy the folders back to the original location that don't contain these files but the resultant batch files needs to be run from a separate windows account that has full administrator permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive method which deletes all files in a directory excluding a list of provided file names:

```
public static void DeleteAllExcept(string folderPath, List<string> except, bool recursive = true)
{
    var dir = new DirectoryInfo(folderPath);
    
    //Delete files excluding the list of file names
    foreach (var fi in dir.GetFiles().Where(n => !except.Contains(n.Name)))
    {
        fi.Delete();
    }

    //Loop sub directories if recursive == true
    if (recursive)
    {
        foreach (var di in dir.GetDirectories())
        {
            DeleteAllExcept(di.FullName, except, recursive);

            //Delete directory if empty
            if (!di.EnumerateFileSystemInfos().Any())
            {
                di.Delete();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So you need to compile a list of files which you do not want to delete and then call the method:

```
string myDir = @"C:\TestDirectory"
List<string> keepFiles = new List<string>();

keepFiles.Add("test.txt");
keepFiles.Add("picture.png");
keepFiles.Add("file.pdf");

DeleteAllExcept(myDir, keepFiles, true);
```

The `TestDirectory` has a structure like:

```
-\
-\test.txt
-\test2.txt
-\test3.txt
-\img\
-\img\picture.png
-\img\banner.png
-\img\temp.jpg
-\files\
-\files\sheet.xls
-\files\file.pdf
```

So the files `test2.txt`, `test3.txt`, `banner.png`, `temp.jpg` and `sheet.xls` will be deleted.

Comment: Good answer but leaves empty directories